# Accessing Selenium IDE variables form javascript code inside a rollup?

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

I'm using javascript in order to define a rollup for Selenium IDE. 
When I'm pushing the store command:

```
manager.addRollupRule({name: 'temp',
                       description:
                             .
                             .

commands.push({command: 'storeLocation', target: 'currentURL'});
```

Is it possible to access `currentURL` from the javascript file? I know I can use it like this:

```
commands.push({command: 'store', target:'javascript{storedVars["currentURL"];}', value: 'var2'});
```

but how can I access `currentURL` inside the javascript and not as Selenium command? 
Something like this `var3 = storedVars["currentURL"]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Taking your example this should work:

```
commands.push({
command: 'storeLocation'
, target: currentURL
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be evaluate any expression inside JavaScript using `getEval` function. Following might be your answer, check please:

```
commands.push({command: 'getEval', target: "javascript{var4=storedVars['currentURL']}"});
```

But answer of scott as following is not working:

```
commands.push({
  command: 'storeLocation'
  , target: currentURL
});
```

Because JavaScript scope is not accessible inside inline JavaScript snippet of `commands.push({..})`